# Elsevier (EES) asks not to embed figures in the manuscript (LaTeX)

Tags: elsarticle

I have submitted my TeX manuscript to an Elsevier journal using elsarticle.cls.

I uploaded following files.
1. title.pdf
2. title.tex
3. references.bib
4. figures.eps (multiple figures)

EES built a PDF correctly and every thing looked good, so I authorized it. But next day, it was returned because:

> 1) Please do not embed your tables and figures in your manuscript
>   text. Please place them at the end of your Manuscript file.

I don't understand what it means. I attached figures.eps separately. This was my second submission after a revision. The first submission didn't have any problems. Only difference from the first submission is that there is an additional file (.docx) to respond reviewers and several figures were changed.

Have anyone undergone such a problem?

Comment: Is there any reference to the [`endfloat` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat)?

Comment: This question isn't so much about TeX as it is about interpreting an e-mail (?) you've got. If you're not quite sure what they mean by what they said, the best thing would be to simply ask them for a clarification.

Comment: They mean that the figures should not appear among the text, but instead be collated at the end of the document.

Comment: Thank you, Werner. I didn't know about the endfloat package. I'll try it. By the way, in the manual of the endfloat package, the authors write "Elsevier, bless them, does not want floats at the end for submissions to its journals. So there is no reason to use  endfloat with class elsart." But my journal seems to be an exception. They didn't even accept PDF + LaTeX source files. I hope the package work well for my manuscript.

Comment: @Sverre While your statement is spot on; the comments to the question nevertheless are the answer to a badly designed LaTeX template of Elsevier. The documentation of the template as well as the instructions for authors are mute on the placement of floats for the review process, and the mail requesting the changes is also a bit unclear. Finding this question after googling the statement which the OP citet, led me to this site which provided the answer.